# Bootstrap navbar toggle not toggling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So for some reason my bootstrap nav toggle that shows when the page shrinks is not toggling on click.  I have made sure to import the jquery library first so i not sure why it wouldn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JPV Painting Plus</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js\bootstrap.min.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\styles.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <img id="index-banner" src="img\index-banner.jpg"/>
    <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold"></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the javascript file as a stylesheet, you should import it as a `script`.

Notice how when you add a stylesheet you add a `link` element, but for js files you need `script` element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>JPV Painting Plus</title>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <img id="index-banner" src="img\index-banner.jpg" />
  <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold"></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You typed `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js\bootstrap.min.js" />`. It should be `<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`. It is a script, not a stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks. Ill give it the answer when I can

Answer (score 0):

Import the jquery at the end of your html document, before the body end tag for example.
Use

```
<script src="PATH"></script>
```

instead of link tag.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the CDN version of bootstrap over modules. On CDN the toggle works but module didn’t.

Comment: This could easily be a comment not an answer. Take your time and get familiar with the SO [website](https://stackoverflow.com/help)